# platform agnostic rules or workflow engine

Tags: drools, workflow-foundation, rules, rule-engine, business-rules

I have a requirement to use the platform agnostic rules engine which needs to run with my java and .net application. In both the windows and linux platform.

Do we have any opensource/commercial rules engine.  Can someone share some experiences on the same.

thanks
Lokesh

Answer (score 2):

Code Effects engine is compiled for .NET Standard 2.0, so supposedly it can run on both Linux and Windows. You can't develop against it on Java platform, though, only in .NET.